# kafka + how to verify if kafka broker leaders are balanced with kafka cli commands

Tags: apache-kafka

we have Kafka cluster with different versions

**kafka cluster confluent with version 1.0**
**kafka cluster Apache with version 2.7**

we want to test the leader if balance on our topics
the target is verify on each topic that leaders are balanced to partitions

here is example when Kafka broker leaders are balanced

we can see that we have 4 (1001 ) , 3 (1002 ) , 3 ( 1003 )

```
Topic:drive.car.cost.val           PartitionCount:10     ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:segment.bytes=53687091,retention.bytes=53687091
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 0    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1002,1003        Isr: 1001,1002,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 1    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1003,1001        Isr: 1002,1001,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 2    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1001,1002        Isr: 1001,1002,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 3    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1003,1002        Isr: 1001,1002,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 4    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001,1003        Isr: 1002,1001,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 5    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1002,1001        Isr: 1002,1001,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 6    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1002,1003        Isr: 1001,1002,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 7    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1003,1001        Isr: 1002,1001,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 8    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1001,1002        Isr: 1001,1002,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 9    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1003,1002        Isr: 1001,1002,1003
```

and here is example that leader brokers are not balanced

we can see that we have 1 (1001 ) , 2 (1002 ) , 7 ( 1003 )

```
Topic:drive.car.cost.val           PartitionCount:10     ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:segment.bytes=53687091,retention.bytes=53687091
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 0    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1002,1003        Isr: 1001,1002,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 1    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1003,1001        Isr: 1002,1001,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 2    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1001,1002        Isr: 1001,1002,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 3    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1001,1003,1002        Isr: 1001,1002,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 4    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1002,1001,1003        Isr: 1002,1001,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 5    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1002,1001        Isr: 1002,1001,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 6    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1001,1002,1003        Isr: 1001,1002,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 7    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1003,1001        Isr: 1002,1001,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 8    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1001,1002        Isr: 1001,1002,1003
        Topic: drive.car.cost.val       Partition: 9    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1001,1003,1002        Isr: 1001,1002,1003
```

so we build python script that count and calculate the kafka leaders , and verify if we have balanced

but I want to know if kafka itself have some cli that can tell us if leaders are balanced per partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using  Confluent ? If so they provide command line tool , notice you would need to gather metrics as well to make it work

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/rebalancer/index.html

```
   ./bin/confluent-rebalancer execute --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --metrics-bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --throttle 10000000 --verbose --dry-run
```

Output would look like

```
Computing the rebalance plan (this may take a while) ...
You are about to move 17 replica(s) for 14 partitions to 4 broker(s) with total size 827.2 MB.
The preferred leader for 14 partition(s) will be changed.
In total, the assignment for 15 partitions will be changed.
The minimum free volume space is set to 20.0%.

The following brokers will have less than 40% of free volume space during the rebalance:
      Broker     Current Size (MB)  Size During Rebalance (MB)   Free % During Rebalance      Size After Rebalance (MB)    Free % After Rebalance
      0          413.6              620.4                        30.1                         519.6                        30.5
      2          620.4              723.8                        30.1                         520.8                        30.5
      3          0                  517                          30.1                         520.8                        30.5
      1          1,034              1,034                        30.1                         519.6                        30.5

Min/max stats for brokers (before -> after):
      Type  Leader Count                 Replica Count                Size (MB)
      Min   12 (id: 3) -> 17 (id: 0)     37 (id: 3) -> 43 (id: 3)     0 (id: 3) -> 517 (id: 1)
      Max   21 (id: 0) -> 17 (id: 0)     51 (id: 1) -> 45 (id: 0)     1,034 (id: 1) -> 517 (id: 3)
No racks are defined.

Broker stats (before -> after):
  Broker     Leader Count    Replica Count   Size (MB)            Free Space (%)
      0          21 -> 17        48 -> 45        413.6 -> 517       30.5 -> 30.5
      1          20 -> 17        51 -> 44        1,034 -> 517       30.5 -> 30.5
      2          15 -> 17        40 -> 44        620.4 -> 517       30.5 -> 30.5
      3          12 -> 17        37 -> 43        0 -> 517           30.5 -> 30.5

Would you like to continue? (y/n):
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such command built into Kafka.

Unless you are concerned about network saturation to a specific broker, the leader information doesn't track "balance of data"